# incorrect JSON format in firebase and ionic 2

Tags: json, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am working on an ionic 2 project I am using firebase for my database I want the data on particular date so I have used following json

```
{
  "Daily" : {
    "05032018" : [ "p003", "p001" ]
  },
  "Questions" :  {
    "q" : {
      "p003" : [
            {"cans" : "1"},
            {"o1" : "Gandhar"},
          {"o2" : "Faisal"},
          { "o3" : "Sachin"},
          {"o4" : "Pranati"},
          {"question" : "What is vdfvdfgyour name?"},
          {"topic" : "probability"}

      ],
      "p004" : [
        { "cans" : "1"},
        {"o1" : "Gandhar"},
          {"o2" : "Faisal"},
          { "o3" : "Sachin"},
          {"o4" : "Pranati"},
          {"question" : "What is iosiodoi name?"},
          {"topic" : "probability"}

      ],
        "p001" : [
        { "cans" : "1"},
        {"o1" : "Gandhar"},
          {"o2" : "Faisal"},
          { "o3" : "Sachin"},
          {"o4" : "Pranati"},
          {"question" : "What is asasas name?"},
          {"topic" : "probability"}

      ]
    },
    "type" : "Apti"
  }
}
```

Now for getting data from firebase I am using following function

```
loadData() {
    return this.afd.list('/Questions/q/p003').valueChanges();
  }
```

but I am getting the data with keys 0 and 1 with values of json but I am not getting the original given keys in my json.

can anyone give the correct json format to use ?

Comment: what is the data that you are getting?

Comment: I am getting data like (2) ["1", "Gandhar"]
0
:
"1"
1
:
"Gandhar"   here I am not getting the actual key data I am getting 0  and 1 with the values

Comment: in your json, do this `"p003" : [{ //write all the data }],
      "p004" : [{ //write all the data}]` and tell me if it works to write it as an answer

Comment: its giving me key but its still giving me it with 0 and 1 i think it giving it in array form not as object